# Salience value in rules (drl)

Tags: drools

I have very recently started working on drools. I want to create a drl file where i can choose on priority of rules to be fired.
Say:
Rule 1: says that the price if greater than 1000 don't buy
Rule 2 : says if the price between 700 and 1000 negotiate

so if rule 1 breaks(that is the price is greater than 1000); it is pointless to go ahead with rule 2.

So could you please guide me on how to go about with such scenarios

Also, any good tutorials on Drools and how to create drool files would be of great help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two rule definitions can be used for your use case.

```
rule 1
when
   $item: Item (price > 1000)
then
   modify ($item) {
       doNotBuy = true
   }

rule 2
when
   $item: Item(price>1000, price<700)
then
   modify($item) {
       negotiate = true
   }
```

The basic thing with the Drools is, it evaluates the `when` parts of your rules and decides whether `then` part of a rule is to be executed. You do not need to do anything except that writing meaningful conditions in the `when` part.

`salience` is a totally different beast and I recommend you to stay away from it, at least until you get familiar with drools.

Comment: the explanation is really good, but can you please give me links to some tutorials where i can study on how to make such rules

Comment: I really don't know why you can't use Google to locate some links. Recommending stuff about Drools is "iffy", as it develops very quickly; books may be out of date...   http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redhat.com%2Frhecm%2Frest-rhecm%2Fjcr%2Frepository%2Fcollaboration%2Fsites%2520content%2Flive%2Fredhat%2Fweb-cabinet%2Fhome%2Fresourcelibrary%2Fwhitepapers%2Fbrms-design-patterns%2Frh%3ApdfFile.pdf&ei=vnv7UqbUJIfMtAbfooD4DA&usg=AFQjCNGNLv6wq17O8--L_J5cTl5SdamVCA&sig2=3b_7N5ItNyT974FRHacUVQ&bvm=bv.61190604,d.Yms

Comment: Drools documentation would be a good starting point. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch09.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to emulate procedural behaviour in a production system by applying salience. There is no such thing as "to go ahead with [another] rule". Think of the Rule Engine evaluating all conditions simultaneously, and write your constraints so that all your rules are independent from each other.

As for books, Google will find you some, and you can also search for design patterns in production systems.

Comment: could you please share some links where a tutorial or a reference is given

Answer (score 1):

I you want to learn more about drools you could start with these 2 books:

http://www.packtpub.com/drools-developers-using-jboss-cookbook/book

http://www.packtpub.com/jboss-rules-5-x-developers-guide/book

Hope it helps,